# jQuery variable isn't updating after ajax execution

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a load more button, that each time I clicked should show 10 new results, but the offset value isn't updating so it is always showing me the same 10 results

```
$("#loadmore_timeline").on("click",function(e){ // When btn is pressed.
        e.preventDefault();
        $number = 10;
        $offset = $number;
        $("#loadmore_timeline").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.ajax({
            url: jx.ajaxurl,
            method: "POST",
            cache : false,
            data:{
                "action": 'more_timeline_activities_ajax',
                "number": $number,
                "offset": $offset
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("table.activity_timeline").append(data.content);
                $offset = $offset + 10;
                $("#loadmore_timeline").attr("disabled",false);
                console.log($offset);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('error:', error);
            }
        });
    });
```

I think it's happening because the number value is constant and it's the value that uses as a reference, but I don't know how to get and update this value in a different place.

Comment: So define the offset outside so on every click it gets updated, not overwritten

Comment: @epascarello but I would still need a variable to save the iteration, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So move the varaibles

```
$number = 10;
$offset = $number;
```

outside of the click event so you are not overriding them on every click.

```
var $number = 10;
var $offset = $number;
$("#loadmore_timeline").on("click",function(e){ // When btn is pressed.
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loadmore_timeline").attr("disabled",true); 
    ...
```

Comment: you're right! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. thanks!